# Conjunction with "and" and "then"

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions

I wrote this sentence:

> In the subsequent sections, after reviewing the existing approaches, we present our approach **and then an algorithm to implement it.**

Should I break the sentence into two sentences, like "*... and then an algorithm to implement it is presented*"? or I can write it as above?

Comment: I think "and" is a coordinator not a cinjunction

Comment: @Cardinal It's a matter of what grammatical sect you're in communion with. Traditional grammar calls *and* a "coordinating conjunction".

Comment: Instead of using *and then*, you could use *followed by*, which sounds better in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Your sentence is grammatically unexceptionable, and conforms to the prevailing second-rate academic taste for superfluous repetition and subordination.

Why do you have three distinct terms signifying sequence—*subsequent*, *after*, *then*? None of them is needed: the sequence is evident in the bare conjunction. Me, I like things simpler:

> We review the existing approaches, define our own approach, and offer an algorithm for implementing it.

If your 'sections' are numbered you can make things even clearer for readers:

> Section 2 reviews existing approaches, Section 3 defines our own approach, and Section 4 offers an algorithm for implementing it.

Comment: Thank you for advice, but you admit that my conjunction with "and then" is ok! however I myself prefer your style now.

Comment: @Ahmad Your English is very good, and your instinct when you're unsure is usually sound. I think you've read enough and imitated enough that you're ready to throw away your models and concentrate on *writing*: making things as easy as possible for your readers to understand. Save the complex constructions for when they're needed to express complex ideas.